# Applications can no longer access your online account

Tags: login, 15.04

When i try to start my laptop with Ubuntu 15.04 it just says: "Applications can no longer access your @gmail.com online account". And then it just reboot. So there is no possible chance for me to login, only in guest session. So what can i do? :)

Comment: Those are two separate issues. If you have automatic login enabled, you need to login to Gmail in Settings. If you don't have auto login, your system Gmail session expired and you still need to login in Settings. The reboot is not connected to this at all. Make sure your battery is charged and that the power button isn't stuck down.

Comment: Or possible a single issue this may be related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop/616927#616927

Answer (score 1):

Those are two separate issues. If you have automatic login enabled, you need to login to Gmail in Settings. If you don't have auto login, your system Gmail session expired and you still need to login in Settings. The reboot is not connected to this at all. Make sure your battery is charged and that the power button isn't stuck down.